# Rescue data from ext4 ISO image?

Tags: linux, iso-image, dd, ext4, rescue

so, my SD card got broken and cannot be read completely (escpacially the directory I want to read from has problems).
I was able to create an ISO image of the partition using dd but cannot mount it. Is there a possibility searching for usable files in the image?

Thanks in advance,
Wolle

Comment: A filesystem cannot be both ext4 and ISO 9660. And SD cards would certainly never use ISO 9660 regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, your file is not an ISO, but simply an image of an ext4 partition that you have exported as a file with a .iso extension, but remember, it is not actually an iso (iso files are disk images, but not all disk images are iso's).

instead you need to use DD to write the file back out to a volume, and then you will be able to leverage tools like photorec.

I'd recommend using a virtual machine running a linux flavor from live cd, so you can create a virtual hdd file for writing your partition out to, without having to allocate physical storage to the task.

also if you find many of your files unrecoverable from your image, try taking a new image using ddrescue. it takes a very long time, but it can be worth it if your files are valuable enough to you.

Comment: So there is no way of just reading the raw data of an image and trying to restore files? I'm just thinking, when trying to mount a virtual hdd in a virtual machine, it will fail, too.

Comment: you don;t have to have the drive mounted in order to use photorec or other file carving/scavenging utilities, but you do need the file converted to a device. thats what writing the image out to a vhd will get you.